# How to make HTMLCollection not live?

Tags: javascript, html

How to make HTMLCollection not live?

```
var cells = someTable.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Is live collection, meaning that when I add new td to table, cells length will increase by 1. How can I make it not live?

Comment: Make it into an array; duplicate explains how.

Comment: @CBroe: One doesn't *have* to convert to array after the fact; one can use `querySelectorAll` instead to get a snapshot `NodeList`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

One is to use `querySelectorAll` instead; it returns a "snapshot" `NodeList`:

```
var cells = someTable.querySelectorAll("td");
```

Another option is to convert it into an array:

```
var cells = Array.from(someTable.getElementsByTagName("td"));
```

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is relatively new, but can be polyfilled for older browsers. Or if you want to support old browsers without polyfilling, use `slice`:

```
var cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(someTable.getElementsByTagName("td"));
```